# operator++(int) overload with abstract base class and Wall

Tags: c++, reference, abstract-class

I am currently creating a set of iterators which will differ in implementation detail, but will be used in the same algorithms. For this reason, they must all have the same interface. To achieve this, I created an abstract iterator class and inherited from this class in all further iterators.

This should give you an idea of what my code looks like:

```
class INodeIterator
{
public:
    virtual ~INodeIterator() {};
    virtual bool operator!= (const INodeIterator& other) =0;
    virtual bool operator== (const INodeIterator& other) =0;
    virtual INodeIterator& operator++ () =0;
    virtual INodeIterator& operator++ (int i) =0;
    virtual Node& operator* () =0;
};

class NodeIterator : public INodeIterator
{
public:
    /* snip */
    NodeIterator& operator++ (int i)
    {
        NodeIterator tmp(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return(tmp);
    }
};
```

Now I am facing the same problem as in [C++ post-increment operator overload in iterators (compiling with -Wall -Werror)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846221/c-post-increment-operator-overload-in-iterators-compiling-with-wall-werror): My operator++(int) implementation throws a warning (gcc 4.8.0) that a reference to a temporary is returned. The solution in the linked question was to just return the object instead of the reference.

However, this will not work for me. If I change both interface and derived class to return an object instead of a reference, the following errors appear (excerpt, additional file names etc. removed):

```
INodeIterator.h:16:27: error: invalid abstract return type for member function ‘virtual INodeIterator INodeIterator::operator++(int)’
     virtual INodeIterator operator++ (int i) =0;
                           ^

NodeIterator.h:33:22: error: invalid covariant return type for ‘virtual NodeIterator NodeIterator::operator++(int)’
         NodeIterator operator++ (int i);
                      ^

INodeIterator.h:16:27: error:   overriding ‘virtual INodeIterator INodeIterator::operator++(int)’
     virtual INodeIterator operator++ (int i) =0;
                           ^
```

Changing the return type to object on the derived class but not on the abstract class expectedly returns a "conflicting return type specified" error.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Why not use a class template and generic algorithms?

Comment: @DyP I am not overly familiar with templates and have tried to avoid them so far. Besides, the code in the iterators will be substantially different, so templating the iterator doesn't seem like a good idea. Or were you talking about templating the algorithms?

Comment: Yes, it's rather a problem that can be solved by templating the algorithms.

Comment: I did think about that, but I would still like to have a base class defining all my iterator methods. Otherwise, e.g. when I forget to create some required method, I will not find out before an algorithm is actually instantiated with the faulty class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change design: let's NodeIterator holds INodeIterator as a pointer. All methods of NoteIterator will delegates to the holding INodeIterator object. In that case you can use correct signature:

```
struct IteratorInterface {
    virtual ~IteratorInterface() {}
    virtual std::unique_ptr<IteratorInterface> clone() const = 0;
    virtual void next() = 0;
};

class Iterator {
    std::unique_ptr<IteratorInterface> impl;
public:
    Iterator(std::unique_ptr<IteratorInterface> r) : impl(std::move(r)) {}
    Iterator(const Iterator &r) : impl(r.impl->clone()) {}
    Iterator& operator++() {
        impl->next();
        return *this;
    }
    Iterator operator++(int ) {
        Iterator tmp(*this);
        impl->next();
        return tmp;
    }
    void swap(Iterator &other) {
        other.impl.swap(impl);
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    struct IteratorInterfaceImpl : IteratorInterface {
        int i;
        IteratorInterfaceImpl() : i(0) {}
        virtual std::unique_ptr<IteratorInterface> clone() const {
            return std::unique_ptr<IteratorInterface>(new IteratorInterfaceImpl(*this));
        }
        virtual void next() {
            i += 1;
        }
    };
    Iterator tmp(std::unique_ptr<IteratorInterface>(new IteratorInterfaceImpl()));
    tmp++;
    ++tmp;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "delegate to the holding INodeIterator object".. but the latter does not have any implementation!?

Comment: of cause in that case NoteIterator must be constructed by the INodeIterator parameter and INodeIterator must be clonable.

Comment: +1, it works, though every time you post-increment, you'll have to dynamically allocate memory..

Comment: the post increment is always expensive for object with nontrivial copy

Comment: Iterators shouldn't be expensive to copy IMO. On the other hand, if you use the OP's approach and only have `INodeIterator`, it's the same problem for copying iterators.

Comment: Marking this as accepted, because it seems to be the best solution. However, I don't want to put one more layer on my iterators at this time, so I decided to just go without the postfix increment operator for now.

Answer (score 1):

The only sane way I can think of is to return `void` from `INodeIterator::operator++(int)` - i.e. nothing.

You can't return a reference from the post-increment operator, because you'll have to create an actual object (storing the previous value) of which you return a reference. This object is either dynamically allocated and would have to be destroyed (had to call `delete` explicitly on the reference returned) or it is a "local variable" of `operator++(int)` and will get destroyed before returning:

```
virtual NodeIterator& operator++(int)
{
    NodeIterator prev_value(*this);
    ++(*this);
    return prev_value; // dangling/invalid reference, `prev_value` is destroyed
}

virtual NodeIterator& operator++(int)
{
    NodeIterator* pPrev_value = new NodeIterator(*this);
    ++(*this);
    return *pPrev_value; // have to explicitly call delete on the returned ref...
}
```

You also cannot return an object of type `INodeIterator` from `INodeIterator::operator++(int)` because it's an abstract class.

Comment: Returning void from operator++(int) is loathsome. Please keep operator overload specifications standard!

Comment: @Bathsheba I agree that it's not perfect, but it won't lead to subtle errors. If you try to use the return value, you'll get a compile-time error.

Comment: True ;-) Now I feel bad for downvoting you! Feel free to indulge in a bit of tit-for-tat. Wow, I just reversed it and +1 as I didn't spot the compile time error guard.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the error

```
INodeIterator.h:16:27: error: invalid abstract return type for member function ‘virtual INodeIterator INodeIterator::operator++(int)’
     virtual INodeIterator operator++ (int i) =0;
```

Is because your pure virtual function returns a abstract class object.

One solution is to use new operator and return the object created in heap, which is safe.

```
 virtual INodeIterator& operator++ (int i) =0;

    NodeIterator& operator++ (int i)
    {
        NodeIterator* tmp = new NodeIterator (*this);
        ++(*this);
        return(*tmp);
    }
```

Comment: And now you return a reference which is to be deleted.. I don't think this is good either..

Comment: What about returning auto_ptr then?
 `std::auto_ptr<NodeIterator> operator++ (int i)
  {        
      return std::auto_ptr<NodeIterator> ( new NodeIterator(*this));   
  }`

Comment: `auto_ptr` is deprecated as of 2011. The point of returning something from `operator++(int)` is that you can use the result in another expression, like `NodeIterator res = my_node_iterator++;` or `my_node_iterator++ ++;` You can't do that if you return a pointer (different semantics).

Answer (score 0):

Your prototype is incorrect. It should be

`NodeIterator operator++ (int i)`

That is, drop the reference return, otherwise you are returning a reference to something that has gone out of scope (your `tmp`) Not a good idea!

And the compiler was being very helpful in letting you know this!

Not quite what you wanted to hear I know.

Comment: I already tried that, see my question. This produces a different compiler error.

Comment: It's time for you to consider some of the alternatives other folk are suggesting. Please don't abuse the post-increment operator though! (Perhaps one reason why you can't overload operators in Java is to protect us from ourselves).